# Rails design pattern: groups and individuals in one distribution list class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, database-design

I have a class User, which has many Events and belongs to many Groups. I want to allow user to create Event and restrict who he wants the invite by Group, by user id or by both.

I am thinking creating a table Invitee to store all users' id and events id. For each Event, when user A chooses to invite group Z and users B and C, I will query group Z to find all user id of the members and add them to Invitee table, together with B and C's user id.

I think it is might not be the best way to do it. I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in to polymorphic associations: basically you want invitations that can be either entity type.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I thought about polymorphic associations (say Invited) but it seems to me that it might be tricky to overload Invited methods to accommodate each type. For example, when I want to send emails to invitees, I need to have two methods to handle group (i.e., additional query for user ids) vs. individuals. Could you comment on this?

Comment: You'll have to handle them differently no matter what, right? There are several ways this could be handled--just depends where you want that code to live, or how you're retrieving invitations to send, and so on,

Comment: True. If I have many methods for Invited, then it is better to let the class Invited handle it for decoupling purposes. Another small benefit is that I can loop through Invited for a particular event as multiple types. For now, I just use Invited as a class to hold a list of users so that the host can send invites to.

Comment: This is what I did: I have an Invite class, which foreign key event_id, and belongs_to :invitable, :polymorphic => true. Then I have Event.invite({:invitable_type => "Group", :invitable_id => "1"}, {:invitable_type => "User", :invitable_id => "2"}). Is this what you have in mind?